# Running multiple thread groups consecutively not working

Tags: jmeter

I'm running a load test on jmeter, I have to send the same requests to a server at different rates (i. e. 20 RPS, 40 RPS, 60 RPS, etc.). I need logs for each rate so I decided to separate each rate in its own thread group, and try to run them consecutively.

So I have the threads:

20RPS
40RPS
60RPS
etc...

And I checked the "Run Thread Groups consecutively" checkBox in the Test Plan.

My problem is: It is only running the first thread, then it just treats the test as completed and it wont run the other 4 threads.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more than just your basic setup, it can be any number of things.

How are you confirming that your test is only running one thread group?  If your listener is the 'child' of a thread group and not the test plan it will only report the responses of that thread group and not the entire test plan.

Edit: Added more questions below

Can you provide a bit more information such as:

- Are the samplers in each thread group identical?
- What listeners are being utilized?
- What are the listeners the 'children' of?
- If you [Toggle](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterShortcuts) the other thread groups         off will they run independantly?
- Is there any error being thrown in the jmeter.log after the thread group runs and the others don't?

Comment: I found out because I ran it in the GUI and it only performed the part of the 20 RPS and only logged that part. I have listeners for each thread group, each one is logging to a different file.
Yes, the 4 samplers in each thread group are identical to those on the other thread groups. I'm only varying the amount of hits per second.
Listeners: Transations per Second, Response Time over Time, Hits per Second
Listeners are child of Thread Groups